# Next number in the sequence 2, 4, 3, 10, 5, 5, 28, 11

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

> 2, 4, 3, 10, 5, 5, 28, 11, 7, 8, 82, 29, ?

**What is the next term in this sequence?**

I was asked this in an interview, but my time ran out and I couldn't figure out the pattern. I see a lot of terms of the form $3^n + 1$ here - maybe that is helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First

> Group it like this
>  $(2)\  (4, 3)\  (10, 5, 5)\  (28, 11, 7, 8)\  (82, 29, ?,...)$

I think it's

> the first term of each group is $3^{(i-1)}+1$ where $i$ is the group number.

and

> the second term for groups $\ge 2$ is $3^{(i-2)}+2$ where $i$ is the group number.

and

> the third term for groups $\ge 3$ is $3^{(i-3)}+4$ where $i$ is the group number.

in general

> The groups will have $i$ terms, where $i$ is the group number and
>  each term $j$, $1\le j\le i$ is $3^{(i-j)}+2^{(j-1)}$

Therefore

> The third element of the fifth group is $3^{(5-3)}+2^{(3-1)}$

or

> $13$

Postscript:

> As Jaap Scherphuis correctly points out, the formula doesn't fit the "8" in the sequence, which the formula calculates as a 9.  Florian F suggests that if you replace $2^{(j−1)}$ by ${{j(j−1)} \over 2}+1$, it would fix it (the final answer remaining the same), but it seems much more likely the "8" was a typo and should have been "9".

Comment: Interview questions like this are excellent! By that I mean they are excellent at helping you definitively weed out companies/jobs that you had previously considered.

Comment: It would be nice to see the answer in table format, where the sequence forms the diagonals. There does seem to be a mistake in the given sequence though, as that 8 should be a 9.

Comment: To get an 8 you can replace $2^{(j-1)}$ by ${{j (j-1)} \over 2}+1$, but it starts to be uncomfortably complicated.  Anyway, the answer is 13 either way.

Comment: Maybe the goal wasn't to see if he could find the answer, but to see if he was smart enough not to spend too much time on a very difficult question and to move on to the next one. "Will you let an obstacle stop you or will you keep on being productive?". Or "how does he deal with failure?" Recruitment processes can be devious.

Comment: If the interviewer is present, it could also be to see how you approach the problem, how inventive you are searching for a solution.  The OP noted the $3^n+1$ pattern, that could be worth something.

Comment: Using 1,2,4,7 (j(j-1)/2+1) instead of 1,2,4,8 (2^j) I think is still reasonable here, since as a sequence it just means you add one, add two, add three, etc.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your solution. To address other people's comments, I think @AlainReve may be right as I was given 4 minutes for this problem. Also, I double-checked and that term was indeed an $8$.